# How can I reduce the "zeroes" effect on a high dimensional sparse matrix?

Tags: python, data-science, multilabel-classification

I'm a newbie at python and data science and I'm trying to run a multilabel classification. However, I have over 2.000.000 observations and 230 categories to predict. The main problem here is that my sparse matrix will result in a lot of "zeroes", so the accuracy will be monstrously high (classifying everything as 0).

For example, the category "animals" appears 11340 times. So, there will be over 1,9m "0" in this category.

Is there a way to reduce this effect? I used binary relevance, naive Bayes and some others but i think the main issue is the data frame itself.

Comment: You have a imbalanced data set. There are many ways to handle this. This article might be helpful: https://medium.com/coinmonks/practical-tips-for-class-imbalance-in-binary-classification-6ee29bcdb8a7

Comment: For such an imbalanced problem, you probably do not want to use accuracy as a metric. Take a look at precision, recall, or f1 score. [Scikit-learn has many metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#from-binary-to-multiclass-and-multilabel) that offer better evaluation options than accuracy for imbalanced classification problems.